# ngx-device-detector IE Issue on angular 8

Tags: angular

I am using ngx-device-detector with version 1.4.2 on my angular 8 Project, Plugin works fine in Chrome, but fails on IE11

on Local(dev) throws error as below

[image]

After deploying to Server error coming as below

[image]

[image]

```
**Polyfills.ts**

import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'core-js/es/array';


import 'classlist.js'; // Run npm install --save classlist.js.


import 'web-animations-js'; // Run npm install --save web-animations-js.

import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.

**Package.json**
{
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
"ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.2",
"rxjs": "~6.4.0",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.21",
"@angular/cli": "~8.3.21",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.15.0",
"typescript": "~3.5.3"
}
}

**tsconfig.json**

{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
"node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
"es2018",
"dom"
]
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
"strictInjectionParameters": true
}
}
```

ngx-device-detector is working on angular 11 version on IE11 platform, Do I need to update the angular version from 8 to 11 ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for ngx-device-detector says that for Angular 8 you should be using 1.3.x

https://github.com/KoderLabs/ngx-device-detector#dependencies

I just ran into an issue where I mistakenly upgraded our version to 1.5 and ran into this same issue in our own Angular 8 project.